# How to make the "Make Project" menu to run maven goal in IntelliJ?

Tags: maven, intellij-idea, maven-3

Now our Maven Java projects generate a lot errors in IntelliJ but maven compiles them fine. Our IntelliJ projects is imported from the pom.xml files. So I want to remove those errors by using maven goal to run the `Make Project` in the `Build` menu instead of the built-in one. How do I do that?

Comment: You can't replace this menu functionality. Run maven goals from the Maven Project panel or Maven Run configurations. It will be slower than Make, so I'd recommend configuring your project properly so that it can be built by IDEA, not only by Maven.

Comment: How to do so then? I imported from pom.xml, so it should just compile, turns out it does not

Comment: File a bug at http://youtrack.jetbrains.net/issues/IDEA with a sample project to reproduce.

Answer (score 1):

Every time you modify the pom.xml file into IntelliJ, an information box usually comes up asking you if you want to re-import your dependencies. Click on it and your errors will disappear.